# Save an Object after an error Occured in the current Transaction

Tags: spring, hibernate, transactional

Hi i have the following construction, which runs a raw query and then saves the result. But when an exception occoured on the raw queries, i cannot save my Object any more to indicate that an error happened

```
[c3p0] A PooledConnection that has already signalled a Connection error is still in use!
```

The classes:

```
@Service("myService")
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public class MyService {

    cron(){
        Job job = myDao.nextJob();
        try {
            myDao.myFunction(job);
            job.setStatus(Status.COMPLETE);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            job.setStatus(Status.ERROR);
        }
        myDao.save(job);
    }

}

@Repository("myDao")
public class MyDao extends HibernateDaoSupport {
    @Autowired
    public void setHibernateSessionFactory(@Qualifier("sessionFactory") SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
    }

    public void myFunction(final Job job) {
        final Session session = getCurrentSession();
        session.flush();
        session.doWork(new Work() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Connection con) throws SQLException {
                // do something which creates an SQL error
            }
        }
    }

}
```

what can i do to get a new working session to get my object saved?

Comment: Why don't you use Spring Data JPA? Why do you try to access the Connection yourself?

Comment: because i run batch updates with jdbc and i think the raw-queries are not the point

Answer (score 0):

**1)** It looks like you are not releasing the connection to the connection pool after an error, and trying to reuse it.

**2)** Instead of `final Session session = getCurrentSession()` create a new session using openSession() as below:

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionAnnotationFactory();
final Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
```

Try to create new session for each transaction, if you use `getCurrentSession` and any error occurs or not in the transaction, then the maintainence(closing/flushing etc) of the session object is done by hibernate and not by the programmer. Make use of `getCurrentSession` for single threaded environment.

3) By default a Connection object is in **auto-commit** mode, which means that it automatically commits changes after executing each statement. Check whether have you altered its property? Use `Connection.commit()` to commit the connection.

Comment: sorry this bug creeped in while writing the example code, the error still persists

Comment: check the status set to the job object in catch block and myDao.save(job) via debugging. check whether the control goes through catch block.

Comment: yes it works, the error occours at  myDao.save(job);